# How to rebuild a Widget everytime it gets to the top of the route?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have 3 widgets A,B,C
from A I push B and set a .then to print a debug message
if I return to A (from B) the .then fires and the message is printed
but if from B I push a replacement C and then return to A, the .then does not fire
so all to rebuild a widget every time the user returns to it

Context: In my quiz app, I have a home screen with a button that should only show up if the user is on a quiz (if they started a quiz and not finish, as the data is saved on device), a resume button, but not only that resume button should display only if the user is on a quiz, but it should display some quiz stats like what disciplines and all many question and so on...

So I need to rebuild that home screen every time the user returns to it

What I have tried:

Riverpod: Even though I don't like that solution in this scenario because set the state of a riverpod means I have to set another entire set of data at once, and not only that data is extense (a list of question, what current question the user is, what was the answers the user gave and so on) but I also already save the quiz peace by peace, one integer here when the user goes to next question, on integer there when the user select an answer... But even trying to use riverpod, when returning to the home screen the homescreen is still with outdated info, as the riverpod only updates visible widgets.

navigatorObserver: I tried to use observers didPop didPush to check if the current route is at the top, and if so call a function on that, but I cound't even pass the check part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I posted the detailed solution with code below, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a **RouteObserver** with a **mixin** that implements **RouteAware** to accomplish my goal.

How to do:
First we need to instantiate a observer, in my case I used a global variable.

```
final routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();
```

Then I passed it to the **navigatorObservers** in the **MaterialApp**.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      (...)
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
    );
  }
```

With this I created a **mixin** that extends **State** (so I can use *context*) that implements **RouteAware** (so I can use it's functionalities)

```
mixin RouteAwareMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T>
    implements RouteAware {(...)}
```

Then I **overriden** the RouteAware **functions** to call the functions onActivate and onDeactivate (more on that in the next step)

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)! as PageRoute);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    onActivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    onActivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    onDeactivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    onDeactivate();
  }
```

On that mixin I created two functions that will be overriden later by the classes that uses this mixin, one function for when activating the widget (widget gets or returs to the top of the stack), and one for when the widget gets deactivated (get poped out of the stack of some route get pushed on top of it)

```
  void onActivate() {
    print('MixinActivate: $this');
  }

  onDeactivate() {
    print('MixinDeactivate: $this');
  }
```

With all setup I just need to use this **mixin on State classes** to get it's functionalities.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with RouteAwareMixin {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onActivate() {
    _incrementCounter();
    super.onActivate();
  }

  (...)}
```

I will leave a entire demo app showing a demo code, just create a new app and replace the main.dart contents with the ones below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static const String _title = 'Flutter RouteAwareMixin';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with RouteAwareMixin {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onActivate() {
    _incrementCounter();
    super.onActivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter AwareMixin'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('$_counter'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),
                    )),
                child: Text('OpenSecondScreen'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() {
    return _SecondScreenState();
  }
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> with RouteAwareMixin {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onActivate() {
    _incrementCounter();
    _incrementCounter();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SecondScreen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          Text('SecondScreenCounter: $_counter'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ThirdScreen(),
                  )),
              child: Text('OpenThirdScreen'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ThirdScreen')),
    );
  }
}

mixin RouteAwareMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T>
    implements RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)! as PageRoute);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    onActivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    onActivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    onDeactivate();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    onDeactivate();
  }

  void onActivate() {
    print('MixinActivate: $this');
  }

  onDeactivate() {
    print('MixinDeactivate: $this');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on WillPopScope (this will handle the backButton function) in the QuizScreen and do what you want to do.

Comment: I could not achieve my goal using WillPopScope, instead I used a observer with a custom mixin, posted the entire solution, please have a look.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).